# How to generate minified css from Angular (2+)

Tags: css, angular, webpack, sass, angular-cli

I built an angular project in SASS, but I need to be able to use the project's styles in codepen demos. I was thinking that I need to somehow generate minified CSS in the "dist" folder so I can use it as an external source in codepen. The styles are constantly updated in the Angular project, so I'm looking for a solution that automatically generates the CSS file everytime I run the build command.

I'm not sure how to set this up or what to search for. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

By default angular binds the styles directly to the directives which means they are part of the generated javascript, not the css.

You can use the node-sass cli:
https://github.com/sass/node-sass

install it with

```
npm i -g node-sass
```

and use it to convert your sass/scss files

```
node-sass src/style.scss dest/style.css
```

Comment: How do I use this to automatically generate the file when I run `npm build`?

Comment: you can use npm scripts, add "prebuild":"node-sass src/style.scss dest/style.css". then this command will automaticaly run when u call npm build